# Will the reaction shift left or right?

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

[image: Here is the problem I got wrong]

The picture shows the correct answer.

At Eq., I have:

- 3 Mol of A
- 1 Mol of B
- 12 Mol of C

I was looking at each answer in terms of ratio of reactants to products, but its clearly not correct since I got 0.4/2.0. How should I think when approaching this problem?

Comment: Add your equation for the equilibrium to your question.